# wordpress simple google map

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I am use SGM plugin for wordpress and there are grey stripes

This is example from http://clarknikdelpowell.com/wordpress/simple-google-map/

[SGM lat="28.022827" lng="-81.73127" zoom="14" type="TERRAIN" directionsto="62 4th St NW, Winter Haven, FL 33881" content="**Clark/Nikdel/Powell, Inc.**
62 4th St NW, Winter Haven FL 33881
For directions enter your address below"]

[image]

Comment: and what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal sections of the google map are made of out square `div`s. Maybe you are setting all divs to have left/right margins or paddings in your style sheets? Try disabling styles for your webpage and see if this problem still occurs.